# Can Opencover be used with TypeMock Isolator?

Tags: typemock-isolator, opencover

I'm looking for a .NET coverage tool, and had been trying out PartCover, with mixed success.
I see that [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) is intended to replace PartCover, but I've so far been unable to link it with TypeMock Isolator so my mocked-out tests pass while gathering coverage info.

I tried replicating my setup for Partcover, but there's no defined profilename that works with the "link" argument for Isolator. Thinking that OpenCover was based on Partcover, I tried to tell Isolator to link with Partcover, and it didn't complain (I still had Partcover installed), but the linking didn't work - Isolator thought it wasn't present.

Am I missing a step? Is there a workaround? Or must I wait for an Isolator version that is friends with OpenCover?

Comment: OpenCover came from my involvement in maintaining PartCover, but I started from scratch and as such it has new CLSID/PROGIDs etc.

Comment: Makes sense. I suppose even if you hadn't started from scratch, it would make sense to generate new IDs to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: I work at Typemock*

I poked around with the configuration a little bit and managed to get OpenCover to run nicely with Isolator. Here's what you can do to make them work together, until we add official support:

1. Register OpenCover profiler by running `runsvr32 OpenCover.Profiler.dll` (you will need an Administrator's access for this).
2. Locate the file `typemockconfig.xml`, it should be under your installation directory, typically `C:\Program Files (x86)\Typemock\Isolator\6.0`.
3. Edit the file, and add the following entry towards the end of the file, above `</ProfilerList>`:

> ```
> <Profiler Name="OpenCover" Clsid="{1542C21D-80C3-45E6-A56C-A9C1E4BEB7B8}" DirectLaunch="false">
>   <EnvironmentList />
> </Profiler>
> ```

Save the file, you will now have a new entry in the Typemock Configuration utility, called OpenCover. Press the Link button to link them. You will now be able to run your tests using `OpenCover.Console.exe` and Isolator. For example, here's how to run your tests with MSTest:

> ```
> OpenCover.Console.exe 
> -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
> -targetargs:"/testcontainer:"d:\code\myproject\mytests.dll"   
> -output:opencovertests.xml
> ```

There is still a minor issue running this with `TMockRunner -link` (that is, with late linking). I will need to look at it further at work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks so much for this. It wouldn't have occurred to me that the list of supported coverage tools was configurable. 
Too bad adding dotCover isn't as easy.

Comment: No problem! Adding this was pretty straightforward, just adding the CLSID of the profiler, unfortunately it's not the case with dotCover/dotTrace. The good news are that we worked together with the engineers at JetBrains, and support for dotTrace/dotCover is coming in the next version of Isolator. If you'd like to test the pre-release, please ping us at support@typemock.com!

Comment: Oh, that's very exciting @hmemcpy.  I was about to recommend we start using dotCover as our coverage tool until I found that it wasn't friends with Isolator. I'll ask the money people if they'll spring for a newer Isolator and dotCover licenses. If so, I may very well take you up on the offer.