# Can OpenCover get code coverage with Microsoft.Moles.Runner and Nunit?

Tags: nunit, moles, opencover

I'm using OpenCover with Visual Studio2010 professional.
It works well with NUnit on a command-line.

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"C:\bin\NUnit 2.6\bin\nunit-console.exe" -targetargs:"C:\App\Test\ApplicationTest\bin\Debug\ApplicationTest.dll"  -targetdir:"C:\App\bin\Debug" -output:html\result.xml
```

The result is below.

> NUnit-Console version 2.6.0.12051 Copyright (C) 2002-20011 Charlie
>   Poole. Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two,
>   Alexei A. Vorontsov. Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig. All Rights
>   Reserved.
>
> Runtime Environment -    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601
>   Service Pack 1   CLR Version: 4.0.30319.269 ( Net 4.0 )
>
> ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single Execution Runtime:
>   net-4.0 .. Tests run: 2, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0,
>   Time: 42.14 seconds   Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> Committing... Visited Classes 59 of 175 (33.7142857142857) Visited
>   Methods 268 of 4131 (6.48753328491891) Visited Points 15137 of 71763
>   (21.0930423755975) Visited Branches 196 of 8025 (2.44236760124611)
>
> ==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without 
>   correspon ding source) ==== Alternative Visited Classes 59 of 207
>   (28.5024154589372) Alternative Visited Methods 284 of 4371
>   (6.49736902310684)

However it doesn't work with Microsoft.Moles.

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.runner.x86.exe" -targetargs:"""C:\App\Test\ApplicationTest\bin\Debug\ApplicationTest.dll""  /r:""C:\bin\NUnit 2.6\bin\nunit-console.exe""" -targetdir:"C:\App\bin\Debug" -output:html\result.xml
```

This result is below.

> Microsoft Moles Runner v0.94.51023.0 --
>   http://research.microsoft.com/moles -- . NET v4.0.30319 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.
>
> instrumenting...started
>   NUnit-Console version 2.6.0.12051
>     CLR Version: 4.0.30319.269 ( Net 4.0 )
>
> ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single Execution Runtime:
>   net-4.0 .. Tests run: 2, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0,
>   Time: 28.004 seconds   Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> Committing... Visited Classes 0 of 2 (0) Visited Methods 0 of 14 (0)
>   Visited Points 0 of 45 (0) Visited Branches 0 of 2 (0)
>
> ==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without correspon ding 
>   source) ==== Alternative Visited Classes 0 of 2 (0)
>   Alternative Visited Methods 0 of 16 (0)

The result of tests are both correct but no coverage is there.

I tried to change the argument of moles, example '/args:"/domain=Multiple"', -oldType etc, but it never works.

Does anyone notice me what I should do?
Can OpenCover use moles with Nunit?

Comment: I solved the problem by myself.
At first, adding below.

`set CLRMONITOR_EXTERNAL_PROFILERS={1542C21D-80C3-45E6-A56C-A9C1E4BEB7B8}`
http://s135.codeinspot.com/q/2342744

Comment: And I knew NUnit version is more important.
v2.5.2 is worked properly. but v2.6 isn't.

Comment: this has been discussed in previous stackoverflow questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013990/no-code-coverage-information-for-tests-using-moles - the issue here is that moles is also a rewriting profiler and so the two clash - however you can inform moles that it needs to 'chain' to opencover (or any other profiler) so that the two will work in sync

Comment: I greatly appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. 
At first, adding the below code into the batch file or set it as command-line command.

> set CLRMONITOR_EXTERNAL_PROFILERS={1542C21D-80C3-45E6-A56C-A9C1E4BEB7B8}

This link may be helpful. http://s135.codeinspot.com/q/2342744